# Update UiTableview with data getting from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

In my application I'm implementing `UITableView` with data fetching from `URL`.

Everything goes fine.But the problem here is the data coming from backend url is too large. So I am showing `UIActivityIndicatorView` until data fetching completed.

Because of large data it's taking mostly 3 or 4 minutes to fetching. So how to update `UITableView` with data getting from url as soon as possible.

I'm using `asynchronousRequest` to do it.

I used this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skey=%@&user_id=%@",@"XXXXXX",@"3225"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://chkdin.com/dev/api/peoplearoundmexy/?%@",post]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:nil];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (data) {
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *designation=[json valueForKey:@"designation"];
        UIImage *imageobj1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"userpic.jpg"];
        NSData *imagedata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageobj1);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                PeopleNearbyCell *updateCell = (id)[collectionview cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                if (updateCell)

                    cell.UserProfilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];
            });
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

But it's not working. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I wouldn't perform the request within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but rather within the `viewDidLoad`. I believe `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called whenever a new cell is needed, whether when first filling the screen with cells, or when a new cell is scrolled into the screen.

Comment: Even if I hit the server in view did load also , taking too much time to get data. I don't want to wait till data completely loaded , what I'm getting data from url continuously I have to update tableview

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the amount of data you're trying to request? I know some endpoints have an option for that.

Comment: No I didn't try that , can you please let me know

Comment: What API are you using? @SivaSankar

Comment: I think there must be some other api of chkdin which give you list of users profile picture links. If not then use dispatch_get_global_queue and add each request in that global queue and in main queue render user profile in tableview cell imageview.

Answer (score 0):

The network request is asynchronous processing, cellforrowatindexpath is in the main thread, if you need to refresh the table in the network request, you need to write a network request method, and then get the data, in which the method of assignment, then refresh the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lazyload` method. This code in the cellForRow delegate.

```
[cell.loadActivity startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

          // YOUR LOAD FROM URL METHOD HERE.

            // only update UI on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                if (img==nil) {

                    // HANDLE WHEN IMAGE RETRIEVE FAILED
                } else {

                   // ASSIGN IT
                    cell.UserProfilePic.image = img;
                }

                [cell.loadActivity stopAnimating];

            });

        });
```